# Solving $286.84 = \frac{15000\,x\,(1+x)^{60}}{(1+x)^{60}-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, computer-science, finance

I am trying to solve this [Basic APR calculation (via CalculatorSoup.com)](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/financial/apr-calculator-basic.php) with pen on paper.

$$286.84 = \frac{15000\,x\,(1+x)^{60}}{(1+x)^{60}-1}$$

***What have I tried so far?***

[image]

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: $(1+x)^n\neq1+x^n$ where $n\neq1$

Comment: But 1 power n should be 1 always.  Might I ask you to make corrections in above part?

Comment: @Pankaj Hint: You cannot solve this equation for x algebraically. Thus you have to use an approximation method like the [Newton-Raphson method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).

Comment: @Pankaj They were correct. $(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=1}^n{n\choose{k}}x^k$ - see the binomial theorem - when $n$ is a natural number, I should say. When $n$ is not a positive integer the series has infinitely many terms and all you can do is approximate.

Comment: Can you advice how to proceed in this situation using binomial theorem?

Comment: @Pankaj According to what you've written, $(1+x)^60=1+x^60$ which is certainly not true. Thus, the denominator in your second step is incorrect.

Comment: Is that possible for you send the correct steps?

Comment: @Pankaj Which steps/method do you mean?

Comment: I meant, how should I proceed for this situation in this context. Actually, my end goal is to convert the logic in c# programming language.

Comment: @Pankaj I'm afraid I cannot share a solution because I am myself unable to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the Newton-Raphson method in $C\#$. There are many examples on the web.

Firstly let $a=286.84$ and $b=15000$, then we have the equation

\begin{eqnarray*}
 a=\frac{b\cdot i\cdot (1+i)^{60}}{ (1+i)^{60}-1} \\ &\texttt{Multiplying the equation by }(1+i)^{60}-1 \\ a\cdot (1+i)^{60}-a=b\cdot i\cdot (1+i)^{60} \\ & 1+i=q \\ a\cdot q^{60}-a=b\cdot (q-1)\cdot q^{60} \\ & \textrm{Multiplying out the brackets} \\ a\cdot q^{60}-a=b\cdot q^{61} -b\cdot q^{60} \\ & \textrm{Everything on the RHS} \\ 0=b\cdot q^{61}-(a+b)\cdot q^{60} +a
\end{eqnarray*}

Thus we have to find the roots of the 61 degree polynomial $f(q)=b\cdot q^{61}-(a+b)\cdot q^{60} +a$. Next we have to find the first derivative: $$f'(q)=61\cdot b\cdot q^{60}-60\cdot (a+b)\cdot q^{59}$$

And the approximated value of $q$ at the n-th step is

$$q_{n+1} = q_n - \frac{f(q_n)}{f'(q_n)}$$

For verification I attach the table of the values which is made with Excel. The initial value $q_0$ is $1.01$, which is equivalent to $i=0.01=1\%$.

[image]

**Update**

I´ve used [this compiler](https://replit.com/languages/csharp) and [this code](http://theflyingkeyboard.net/c-2/c-newton-method/) for your problem. It works very well. If you have further questions feel free to ask. The output of the compiler is

[image]

$\color{white}{Math.Pow(Number1, Number2)}$

Comment: In the original equation there were 3 numbers. 15000, 60 and 286.84. Can you send updated code such that it allows me to enter these 3 values?

Comment: I used that numbers as you can derive from the output. My first question: Has it worked with the original code, where the function is $f(x)=x^2 + 2x -1$? If yes, you have to replace the function and the derivative.

Comment: @Pankaj I give you a bonus tip: Exponential terms are written as follows: The code for $x^{60}$ is  **Math.Pow(x,60)**

Comment: @Pankaj Any further questions? I have done my part so far.

Comment: Sir, Where can I input the numbers 15000 and 286.84 in your code?

Comment: @Pankaj You put in here: $f(q)=b\cdot q^{61}-(a+b)\cdot q^{60} +a$, which means $\ \ $ **return 15000*Math.Pow(x,61)-(286.84+15000 )*Math.Pow(x,60) +286.84;** $\ \ $for the function. Similar for the derivative.

Comment: @Pankaj Any further questions?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, can you give further info about the x in your second last message? What value will e given for x?

Comment: @Pankaj I'm not sure that I understand your question. Nevertheless I try to give an answer: $x$ is $q$, where $q=1+i$. And $i$ is the interest rate. If you get (approx.) $x=1.0046221$ then the interest rate $i$ is $0.46221\%$

Comment: I still could not understand that `Math.Pow(x,61) what do I have to put in place of x in this equation?

Comment: @Pankaj You do not replace $x$. You write **Math.Pow(x,61)** for $x^{61}$ which means $q^{61}=(1+i)^{61}$. This is part of the 61 degree polynomial where you want to find the relevant root. The program will return approx $x=1.0046221$, thus $i= 0.46221%$

Comment: I meant $i=0.46221\%$